# Input field with customization

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to add the green label to the input field like the following picture. It is one day I am trying different methods but I could not do it yet.
any ideas!!!

I am using bootstrap responsive to design the page layout. The shadow is okay not, only the problem is the label.

[image]

```
<div class="row-fluid">
 <div class="span12" align="center">
  <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Nome"/>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Family" placeholder="Cognome"/>
    </div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say the 'green label' - do you mean just the green square to the left of the input?

Comment: A jsfiddle or codepen would be appreciated also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Bootstrap as your CSS framework, you can achieve this by customizing the `input-group-addon` class.

Read more about it: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.input-group-addon{
  border: 0px !important;
  background: transparent !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 4px !important;
  left: -19px !important;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}
.square{
  width:15px!important;
  height:15px!important;
  background: green!important;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ray716/L5am983g/)

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `:before` pseudo-element on parent div because `input` can not contain other elements. Here is another [`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/323/).

```css
input {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #D0D1D2;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px #DAD9E0;
}
.element {
  position: relative;
}
.element:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #00E09E;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Some Text">
</div>
```